# Image segmentation of Map

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I want to extract map contours using OpenCV.
I applied Bilateral filter and amplified the image.
So I could get better contrasted image.

And I've tried Watershed and meanshiftsegmentation.
But they all require manual operation such as seeds.
And it is hard to apply morph transformation and dilate to the image I've attached because it has different colors and letters.

I'd like you to tell me how to do segmentation automatically.
Thanks.

The Original image is here.

[image: Original]

The Enhanced image is [here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qGhv.jpg)

And this is the what I've done using HSV color difference.
[image]

Comment: No, thanks! (now seriously: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask carefully. Describe your problem and what you have tried.)

Comment: I've changed my question.

Comment: How automatic does it have to be? Do you know how many Parts the map will have?

Comment: I don't know.If I know that, I can apply K-means algorithm.But I don't know. I tried morph transformation and dilate operation to extract seeds, but it didn't work well.

Comment: Do you know that the differen Areas are always colored differently? Than you could segment in hsv space.

Comment: All regions are colored differently.
I have simply tried hsv, but It didn't work well for the letter.
All letters should be included in the region.
That's the difficulty of this post.

Comment: You could try erosion and dilation to fill the holes or find an enclosing contour. but what about e.g. "Homestead" at the top of the map? The text will never be included in the region as it is written across the border. And "simple" is not something that usualy applies to image processing, most takes require a good understanding of image processing and the task that needs to be done, and both of this is kind of lacking here.